# How to use Sqlite CASE WHEN to add more conditions?

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax, case

I would like a row to be evaluated with more conditions when a case is satisfied.

Here's what I came up with:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE Events.CALENDAR_ID + "=?
AND case when " + Events.DTEND + ">0 
then " + Events.DTSTART + ">? end";
```

However, this statement ignores rows that don't satisfy the case.

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE Events.CALENDAR_ID + "=?
case when " + Events.DTEND + ">0 
then AND " + Events.DTSTART + ">? end";
```

Then I came up with this, but Sqlite tells me this is just bad syntax.

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE "case when " + Events.DTEND + ">0 " +
" then " + Events.CALENDAR_ID + "=? AND " + Events.DTSTART + ">? " +
" else " + Events.CALENDAR_ID + "=? end"
```

Comment: This is syntactically correct, but likely to compute the wrong value. What is the *meaning* of your expression?

Comment: I would like the row to be evaluated with an extra WHERE clause "Events.DTSTART>?" if it satisfies the CASE "Events.DTEND>0". Does my statement mean that?

Comment: Yes, your statement is correct (if very unusual). Simpler would be `... WHERE calendar_id = ? AND (dtend <= 0 OR dtstart > ?)`.

Comment: It took me a while for my n00b brain to follow the logic of that statement. But once it did, it is BRILLIANT! Thank you for your insight.

Comment: For a formal proof, look up the [rules of replacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_replacement).